# Using brace initialization for integers

Tags: c++, initialization

Take this code:

```
const auto iGroupId = static_cast<int>(m_cbGroupTo.GetItemData(iGroupIndex));
```

Is it perfectly safe to change it to:

```
const int iGroupId{m_cbGroupTo.GetItemData(iGroupIndex))};
```

? Or am I going about using braces incorrectly?

Comment: One is direct initialization while other is copy initialization.

Comment: *"Is it perfectly safe..."* What is safe? They(direct vs copy) have different meanings.